# Update button in datatable after event

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

i have a simple example for my problem. I have a datatable and i want to disable the button in the footer on a sort, filter or page event. I update the button in the footer, but nothing changes. The other button, in the other form, works fine. If i update the whole table form with "@form", the table would be destroyed.

I found a solution with Primefaces Extensions pe:RemoteCommand (http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/remoteCommand/basicUsage.jsf) ... if i use the onComplete- Methode of the Event and call the remoteCommand than i can update the button in the footer from there.

Can someone explain me that? 
Thank you for your time.

XHTML:

```
   <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="tableform">
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.personList}" var="person" paginator="true"
        rows="5" rowKey="#{person.id}">
        <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{bean.onPaging}"
            update=":outform:buttonOut buttonIn" />
        <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{bean.onFilter}"
            update=":outform:buttonOut buttonIn" />
        <p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{bean.onSort}"
            update=":outform:buttonOut buttonIn" />

        <p:column headerText="id" sortBy="#{person.id}"
            filterBy="#{person.id}">
    #{person.id}        
    </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="name" sortBy="#{person.name}"
            filterBy="#{person.name}">
    #{person.name}
    </p:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">

            <p:commandButton id="buttonIn" value="ButtonIn"
                disabled="#{!bean.visible}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<h:form id="outform">
    <p:commandButton id="buttonOut" value="ButtonOut" disabled="#{!bean.visible}" />
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
 public class Bean {

private List<Person> personList;



private boolean visible = true;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
        personList.add(new Person(i, "Person" +i));
    }
}

public void onPaging(PageEvent event){
    visible = false;
}

public void onSort(SortEvent event){
    visible = false;
}

public void onFilter(FilterEvent event){
    visible = false;
}


public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public List<Person> getPersonList() {
    return personList;
}

public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
    this.personList = personList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you use remoteCommand you can do this:

```
<h:form id="tableform">
.....
<p:remoteCommand name="doAction" actionListener="#{bean.changeFlag}" 
 update="idOfYourDataTable:buttonIn" 
 immediate="true"/> 
.......
</h:form>
```

In the ajax calls:

```
 <p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="doAction();"/>
 <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="doAction();"/>
 <p:ajax event="sort" oncomplete="doAction();"/>
```

In the Bean:

```
public void changeFlag(){
    visible = false;
}
```

Comment: yes i know :) that was my solution in the second passage. But why i cant update the button in the foote from ajax event directly?

Comment: i found an issue for it from 2010 ... i think its the same problem. I think i use the solution with the remoteCommand. Link to issue: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1558

Comment: I will try to replicate at night but I think there is something weird.

Comment: Had you replicate it ? :)